# No password account Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, password, guest-session

Is there any way to create a guest user account (without password) in ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Can you @karel please explain why changing the password that ends up making it a passwordless login for guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As of November 2018)

**You cannot** in 18.04

**You can** in 16.04...it works, and is fully supported until 2021.

**The switch from Unity (16.04) to Gnome (18.04) broke Guest Sessions** - [several parts of the Gnome stack and AppArmor](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/brain-dump-on-guest-session-progress/3717) need to be modified to restore Guest Sessions. It looks to be slow and complex going, and community members with Gnome and/or AppArmor code skills are welcome to join the effort.

**Ubuntu developers [already know](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/guest-sessions-in-18-04-lts-are-they-needed/1714)** that Guest Sessions is an essential feature for many users. They need skilled help, not reminding.

By coincidence, the Mir team has a fascinating not-ready-for-prime-time [kiosk alternative](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/snaps-to-develop-a-web-kiosk-on-ubuntu-core-using-wayland/6424) using Snaps and VMs. Skilled community members are welcome to help develop that, too.